# Como remover a borda da imagem?

Tags: html, css

Eu tenho esta imagem:

1)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

que está a ser usada com icon para um `<input>`:

```
' <input type="button" class=" button_add" />'
```

Com o CSS adicionei-a a uma `li`:

```
input.button_add {
    float: right;
    height: 40px;
    padding-left: 36px;
    background: url("../img/Arrow_Circle_Right-32.png") no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

No ponto 2) dá para verificar que a imagem não tem bordas nenhumas, mas no resultado final a imagem aparece-me assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É possivel fazer essas bordas desaparecerem?

Obrigado pela atenção

Comment: Coloque o seu código e não imagens com o mesmo..

Comment: @CesarMiguel já está alterado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você deve usar:

```
border: none;
background: url("../img/Arrow_Circle_Right-32.png") transparent no-repeat;
```

o transparent do background é pra evitar que sites mais antigos implementem cor no bg.... Uma dica legal, é voce clicar com o botao direito no navegador, em cima do objeto, ir em inspecionar elemento e ao lado, ou embaixo será exibido todo css dele, quase todo navegador moderno permite que você manipule o css do input exibido, dai você pode 'brincar' com o código, adicionar parâmetro, remover, até que atenda sua necessidade.

Comment: o transparent do background é pra evitar que sites mais antigos implementem cor no bg.... Uma dica legal, é voce clicar com o botao direito no navegador, em cima do objeto, ir em inspecionar elemento e ao lado, ou embaixo será exibido todo css dele, quase todo navegador moderno permite que você manipule o css do input exibido, dai você pode 'brincar

Comment: Funcionou. Obrigado. 3min para aceitar como resposta.